# webstorm typescript display compile error

Tags: typescript, webstorm

In webstorm 7, with typescript .9.0.1 installed via node.js, when the typescript compiler runs, I only get the line of error back:

```
C:/Users/mordrax/AppData/Roaming/npm/tsc.cmd world.ts
C:/Users/mordrax/WebstormProjects/CoTWjs/js/world.ts(9,13):
```

However, if I run it in a cmd window, tsc world.ts I get the full picture

```
c:/Users/mordrax/WebstormProjects/CoTWjs/js/world.ts(9,13): error TS2095: Could
not find symbol 'Tile'.
c:/Users/mordrax/WebstormProjects/CoTWjs/js/world.ts(18,41): error TS2095: Could
 not find symbol 'Tile'.
c:/Users/mordrax/WebstormProjects/CoTWjs/js/world.ts(18,61): error TS2095: Could
 not find symbol 'TILEDATA'.
c:/Users/mordrax/WebstormProjects/CoTWjs/js/world.ts(18,88): error TS2095: Could
 not find symbol 'world'.
```

Give.

Comment: Nice ending. 'Give' :)

Comment: hehe, come on, i have to get a +1 for that (do u know where it comes from?). and i just worked out in ubuntu, i do get the full compile error log so it unlikely to not be implemented, just a configuration issue?

Comment: +1 Although I don't know where it comes from. And now you have me super curious. Would appreciate a link or searchable reference :)

Comment: In [The green hornet](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0990407/), Seth's character, while interviewing a job candidate, asks her questions and says Give to prompt her replies. The movie is hilarious! Definitely recommended.

Comment: please vote for [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6507)

Comment: Thanks for the link, i signed up to vote for it, and also for [typescript debugging in webstorm](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7179) as well. Still a work in progress.

Comment: Cool. You can answer your question and I'll vote

Comment: I'm not sure, this is a question of diminishing returns over time, by next month, it'll be useless clutter. I was thinking of voting to close or delete it. Probably close since some on 0.9.0.1 might find it useful...

Comment: @Downvoter, I thought the original question was pretty clear, and the updates means you don't need to read the rest of the question. Why the downvote? Give.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Meta [Discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267434/1757491)

Update (25/8/2013)

This issue has been fixed in typescript 0.9.1

Update (7/8/2013)

Looks like this issue is already on the radar, please vote for it to make it a BIG blip.